# Python - FileNotFound Error when running entire function, not when running line by line

Tags: python, filenotfounderror

I've written a little program to copy pictures from the Windows Assets folder to the Pictures folder and rename them.

When I run the code line by line, the program does what I intended.

But when I run the function (pictures()) I get a "WinError 2 The system cannot find the file specified:".

The callback points to :

```
os.rename(src = path.expandvars(r"%HOMEPATH%\Pictures\Desktop Backgrounds\New Backgrounds\\" + file), \
```

But when I run the applicable part of the code, it executes just fine.

Could there be some reason that the separate parts of the function definition run individually, but the function as a whole doesn't, *other* than a file being in the wrong place/misnamed/etc. ? If not, I'm pretty much at a loss as to why it won't run as a function, since I can't find the problem by running it line by line (since this works).

**Edit:**

The error points to this file not being able to be renamed "0c372e060088d1ed55f9dce0bab55e11608c3c37ec32c01a6f195884cda7beb3".

This file is indeed not in the variable file_list2, but then it's not supposed to be since there's no such file in the relevant directory.

It's as if the interpreter is looking for a file that it thinks should be there, but isn't.

The entire code is:

```
def pictures():

# Import the necessary modules. 
import os
import shutil
from os import path
import datetime
import webbrowser
import cv2

#Create folder in Pictures if needed.
if "Desktop Backgrounds" not in os.listdir(path.expandvars(r"%HOMEPATH%\Pictures")):
    os.mkdir(path.expandvars(r"%HOMEPATH%\Pictures\Desktop Backgrounds"))

if "New Backgrounds" not in os.listdir(path.expandvars(r"%HOMEPATH%\Pictures\Desktop Backgrounds")):
    os.mkdir(path.expandvars(r"%HOMEPATH%\Pictures\Desktop Backgrounds\New Backgrounds"))

 # Copy all files from Assets to New Backgrounds
raw_list = os.listdir(path.expandvars(\
    r"%LOCALAPPDATA%\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState\Assets"))

for raw in raw_list:
    shutil.copy(src = path.expandvars(r"%LOCALAPPDATA%\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState\Assets\\" + raw), \
                dst = path.expandvars(r"%HOMEPATH%\Pictures\Desktop Backgrounds\New Backgrounds"))

# Rename all files in New Backgrounds to a .jpeg extension & datetime to prevent existing file error. 
file_list2 = os.listdir(path.expandvars(r"%HOMEPATH%\Pictures\Desktop Backgrounds\New Backgrounds"))
now = str(datetime.datetime.now())[19:]

for index, file in enumerate(file_list2):
    os.rename(src = path.expandvars(r"%HOMEPATH%\Pictures\Desktop Backgrounds\New Backgrounds\\" + file), \
              dst = path.expandvars(r"%HOMEPATH%\Pictures\Desktop Backgrounds\New Backgrounds\\" + str(index + 1) + now + ".jpeg"))


# Remove all files with small dimensions. 
 # (Continue so the none-type images aren't checked against the < 1919 if statement.) 
    file_list3 = os.listdir(path.expandvars(r"%HOMEPATH%\Pictures\Desktop Backgrounds\New Backgrounds")) 
    
    
    for file in file_list3:
        image = cv2.imread(path.expandvars(r"%HOMEPATH%\Pictures\Desktop Backgrounds\New Backgrounds\\" + file))
            
        if type(image) == type(None):
            os.remove(path.expandvars(r"%HOMEPATH%\Pictures\Desktop Backgrounds\New Backgrounds\\" + file))
            continue
        if image.shape[1] < 1919:
            os.remove(path.expandvars(r"%HOMEPATH%\Pictures\Desktop Backgrounds\New Backgrounds\\" + file))
        else :
            pass
        
# Open Windows Explorer to \New Backgrounds.
webbrowser.open(path.expandvars(r"%HOMEPATH%\Pictures\Desktop Backgrounds\New Backgrounds"))

pictures()
```

Comment: Your indentation make file_list3 inside the for loop of file_list2. So it removes all small dimension files in the `New Backgrounds` folder in the first iteration. In the next iterations, you tried to rename a file in file_list2 but it is already removed.

Comment: Yep, that was it. Next time I'll remember that indentation can mess things up this way and to run through my code to check it first. Thanks a bunch!